# How can I use ln -s to to make a symlink to the Geth chaindata on an external SD card?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

How can I use ln -s to to make a symlink to the Geth chaindata on an external SD card?

I download the Geth chaindata to an external SD card to relieve the internal hard drive from the hard work.

However, I cannot start Mist when Geth is downloading the chaindata to an external SD card.

Luclu @ Ethereum confirmed that it should be possible to use a symlink to the SD card chaindata to allow Mist to run with this configuration.

What should the ln -s command look like?

OS: Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Note, it will take ages to sync the chain to an sd card, why not getting a small external SSD?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem to be the case. It does not seem slow. Could be that the bottleneck is elsewhere than the SD i/o writing speed.

Answer (score 2):

You can either store the whole .ethereum folder or only `.etereum/chaindata` there

```
In -s <path to chain on ext drive> ~/.ethereum/chaindata
```

Comment: I tried to do it with only the chaindata but I was not able to start Mist afterwards

Comment: You would have to remove the old chaindata folder in .ethereum first. have you?

Comment: `ls -lha ~/.ethereum` what does it show? Should have a line like:

`lrwxrwxrwx  1 roland roland   32 apr 25 09:33 chaindata -> /media/roland/SAMSUNG2/chaindata`

Comment: It does have that. But it still didn't work last time I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using some kind of linux/unix, this might also work for mac osx, but I'm unsure if the syntax is the same.

Mount your external medium:

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sdcard
sudo mount /dev/sdX1 /mnt/sdcard
```

Create a symbolic link for the chaindata:

```
ln -s /mnt/sdcard ~/.ethereum/chaindata
```

#### Note:

1. This has to be done before the first start of geth.
2. Whenever you reboot your computer and want to start geth again, make sure the sdcard is mounted!

Comment: Why does it have to be done before the first start of Geth? Isn't it enough just to remove any previous chaindata folder and start resyncing?

Comment: @Vesa yes, deleting the data will do fine.

Comment: After symlinking the folder that geth is writing too is out of space even though the symlinked dir has plenty of space, how do you resolve this?